# Separation of interfaces and implementation

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

From assembly(or module) perspective, what do you think of separation of Interface (1.assembly) and its Implementation (2.assembly)?

In this way we can use some IoC container to develop more decoupling desing..
Say we have an assembly 'A', which contains interfaces only.
Then we have an assembly 'B' which references 'A' and implements those interfaces..It is dependent only on 'A'.

In assembly 'C' then we can use the IoC container to create objects of 'A' using dependency injection of objects from 'B'.
This way 'B' and 'C' are completely unaware (not dependent) of themselves..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're getting at but the only reason to separate interfaces into a separate dll is if **another** project is going to make use of them.

If not, and the same project will use the same interfaces (but multiple times) there is no need to separate them. The IOC container can simply make use of the interfaces within the same assembly.

Consider:

```
Assembly 1:
    IFoo

Assembly 2:
    IOC Container
    ConcreteFooOne : IFoo

Assembly 3:
    IOC Container
    ConcreteFooTwo : IFoo
```

<sub>Note, in this case the IOC container in each of the assemblies would be in charge of taking every `IFoo` instance and assigning it the correct `ConcreteFoo`.</sub>

This makes sense to have a separate assembly for the interfaces. Each of the other dependent assemblies (1 and 2) can use the IFoo interface. On the other hand if `ConcreteFooOne` and `ConcreteFooTwo` where both in the same assembly there would be no need to split out the `IFoo` interface. An IOC container could still leverage "*plug and play*", by switching concrete instances when required.

**Update**

Based on your comment you seem to be worried about tieing the IOC container to na assembly. This is not an issue, and separating the container out to a separate assembly is not a requirement. If anything, I'd class this as a code smell, let alone a pointless action.

Comment: What about having one assembly containing all interfaces and then the other assemblies which references this interface-assembly, where independent of each other.

Then we have only one kind of dependency: interface assembly <---> implem. assembly. The last assembly would be a IoC container which would link the implem. assemblies with the DI mechanism.

Comment: @bonefisher - That doesn't sound right to me. The IOC container (I'm not expert on IOC, lately I've become pretty obsessed with it though) would be in the same assembly as the concrete implementations. I've updated my answer to try and reflect this.

Comment: but you dont want to initialize every container for each assembly, you want to have only ONE IoC container, thus it must 'reside' outside the implem. assemblies